# Splitting time formatted object doesn't work with python and pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I have the simple line of code:

```
print(df['Duration'])
df['Duration'].str.split(':')
print(df['Duration'])
```

Here are the value I have for each print

```
00:58:59
00:27:41
00:27:56
Name: Duration, dtype: object
```

Why is the split not working here? What do I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) doesn't modify column *inplace*, so you need to assign the result to something:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration':['00:58:59', '00:27:41', '00:27:56'], 'other':[10, 20, 30]})

df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].str.split(':')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       Duration  other
0  [00, 58, 59]     10
1  [00, 27, 41]     20
2  [00, 27, 56]     30
```

---

If you want to expand the columns of DataFrame by splitting, you can try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration':['00:58:59', '00:27:41', '00:27:56'], 'other':[10, 20, 30]})

df[['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']] = df['Duration'].str.split(':', expand=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Duration  other hours minutes seconds
0  00:58:59     10    00      58      59
1  00:27:41     20    00      27      41
2  00:27:56     30    00      27      56
```

Comment: and what if I want the split to happen with the same object like [00,58,59]. Can I replace expand=True by append=True?

Comment: @SimonBreton I don't understand `str.split` doesn't have `append=` parameter. What is your expected result?

Comment: What I was doing is actually performing the split correctly but not passing the result anywhere. Is this what you mean by `doesn't modify column inplace`?

Comment: @SimonBreton Yes, exactly. Your `df['Duration'].str.split(':')` is correct, but you don't do anything with the result